# Why does AppleScript continue to find Mail messages in folder after it moves them?

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript that does the following.

1. Activates Mail.app.
2. Looks for messages in a particular folder that is not flagged ("OmniFocus", in my usage).
3. Runs a script on those messages to add them as tasks in Omnifocus.
4. Flags each message.
5. Moves each message to an archive folder.

I added the flagging step (Step 4) because without it, the script was finding the same messages repeatedly even though they had already been moved to the Archive folder. This resulted in many duplicate tasks in OmniFocus. The script works, but the use of the flagged status is a hack and I'd like to understand why AppleScript keeps finding messages in my "OmniFocus" folder when they've already been moved to the "Archive" folder so I can stop relying on flagged status (and just use the folder that the message is in) to determine whether or not a message has already been processed.

I'm running OS 10.8.3 on a 2011 iMac, and the Mail account I'm using this script with is an IMAP account through FastMail.

The script is below.

---

```
property theAccount : "FastMail"

on run
tell application "Mail"
    launch
    synchronize with account theAccount

    set theOFFolder to mailbox "OmniFocus" in account theAccount
    set theArchiveFolder to mailbox "Archive" in account theAccount

    set theTempMessages to {}
    set theMessages to {}
    set theTempMessages to the messages in theOFFolder

    -- Remove the message from the list if it is flagged
    repeat with aMessage in theTempMessages
        if the flagged status of aMessage is false then
            set the end of theMessages to aMessage
        end if
    end repeat

    -- Quit if there are no messages to process
    set theMessageCount to count of theMessages
    if theMessageCount is equal to 0 then
        tell me to quit
    end if

    -- For each message, add it to Omnifocus, flag it, then move it to the FastMail archive folder
    try
        repeat with aMessage in theMessages
            my process_message(aMessage)
            delay 1
        end repeat
    on error m number n
        tell application "OmniFocus"
            log "Exception in Mail action: (" & n & ") " & m
        end tell
    end try

    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        tell application "Mail"
            set flagged status of aMessage to true
            move aMessage to theArchiveFolder
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

try
    tell application "OmniFocus"
        synchronize default document
    end tell
end try

tell application "Mail"
    synchronize with account theAccount
end tell

end run

on process_message(theMessage)
using terms from application "Mail"
    set theSubject to subject of theMessage
    set singleTask to false
    if (theSubject starts with "Fwd: ") then
        -- Whole forwarded messages shouldn't split.
        set singleTask to true
        set theSubject to rich text 6 through -1 of theSubject
    end if

    set theText to "--" & theSubject & return & "message:%3c" & message id of theMessage & "%3e" & return & content of theMessage
    tell application "OmniFocus"
        tell default document
            parse tasks with transport text theText as single task singleTask
        end tell
    end tell
end using terms from
end process_message
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "Move" a mail item, you're possibly asking the mail service to move them, which would require a "Synchronize" in order to execute that action. Your script would need to wait until that action is complete, then continue on its way.

Your method of flagging is probably the most efficient; flagging is done on the local database while moving can only occur when a connection is available, and at prescribed intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, a Message object has a deleted status, you have to check this. If you move a message from a mailbox it keeps re-appearing and leading to duplicates.

```
repeat with aMessage in messages
  if deleted status of aMessage is false then
    move message to theArchiveFolder
  end if
end repeat
```

Mail.app has a ui menu item that delete all messages that are deleted in a mailbox: "Erase deleted items..."